# Securing a large screw hook in drywall without an anchor

Tags: hanging, anchor, drywall-anchor

I have a large-ish screw hook in some drywall that is only supporting a dustpan and hand brush. The hook is not in a stud. As-is, the weight is not too much and the solution works. However, I am always afraid of ripping out the hook when I remove or replace the dustpan, and I can see that the hook is rather wobbly in the wall.

I would like to somehow make this more secure. The issue is that I cannot find any anchors large enough to fit the screw hook. Is there some alternate way of making this hook more secure? This is a garage, so I am open to solutions that might be considered unacceptable for interior use.

[image: Screw hook in drywall]

Comment: How about moving it over a few inches to a stud. Or Take the hook to the hardware store and use it to size an anchor. It is not a huge hook, i am sure an anchor can be found.

Comment: This section of wall is between the corner and the garage door, and it’s just over a foot wide, so there is no stud.

Comment: Where have you looked for the anchors?  They have anchors designed for lag bolts at any hardware store that would surely work for that.

Comment: Your hook is overkill for a dustpan and hand brush. Your biggest concern is accidentally tearing it out when removing the items for use because the hook is obtrusive. Get yourself a 3 or 4 inch screw and put it on an anchor at a slight angle. Patch up the old hole and call it a day.

Comment: Get a hook that doesn't project out so much.  Then there is less "lever arm" wanting to pry the hook out.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cut a 1"x 4" board just long enough to fit between the wall on the right and garage door on the left.

Attach each end with 2 1/2" screws into the studs of said wall and door frame.

Screw hook, ( ***or hooks*** ) into the board.

Other wise like i said in the comments, take it to the store to size and anchor, i have seen ones big enough for that size hook.

*Be aware that an anchor may loosen up over time as well from repeated hanging and removing of the things suspended on it.*

Comment: Great idea. Then I can use this area to hang other things.

Comment: Yes. i see you have perceived my "or hooks" remark. Send beer !

Comment: Agreed - make the board as long as reasonably possible, so it spans across at least 2 studs and gets support from being screwed into them.   Then got more hooks and hang all sorts of implements here.  Given its a garage, this could be good for garden implements, power extension cords, etc.  Could get fancy and add a long narrow shelf on top too for cans or similar storage.

Comment: @Criggie Excellent suggestion with the shelf. I think I will do that!

Comment: +1.  A peg board in a garage is always a good thing.  Beer is deserved.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you move it a few inches either direction to find a stud, but if for some reason you don't want to do that and you don't want to use an anchor then I'd recommend using a hook designed to stay in drywall such as gorilla hooks / monkey hooks.

Comment: I *do* want to use an anchor... do you know of any anchors intended for large screws? And as I added in the comments to the question, there is no stud available to use.

Comment: The monkey hook is a good idea though...

Answer (score 2):

Look for a large adhesive hook, easy to find a one able to hold up to 37+ lbs by spreading force over area on wallboard. No need for some complicated construction project. Remove your screw, put up the adhesive hook, and use immediately. One minute of effort.